# How to embed a folder with swf files?

Tags: javascript, php, swfobject

I've got some trouble with my code.
What I want to do is loading a folder into my embed data.
Is this possible? And how?

```html
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://localhost/swf/">
        <param name='client.allow.cross.domain' value="0"/>
        <param name='client.notify.cross.domain' value="0"/>
        <param name='connection.info.host' value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <param name='connection.info.port' value="30000"/>
        <param name='site.url' value="http://localhost"/>
        <param name='url.prefix' value="http://localhost"/>
        <param name='client.reload.url' value="http://localhost"/>
        <param name='client.fatal.error.url' value="http://localhost/me"/>
        <param name='client.connection.failed.url' value="http://localhost/me"/>
        <param name='external.override.texts.txt'
               value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/override/external_flash_override_texts.txt"/>
        <param name='external.override.variables.txt'
               value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/override/external_override_variables.txt"/>
        <param name='external.variables.txt' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/external_variables.txt"/>
        <param name='external.texts.txt' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt"/>
        <param name='external.figurepartlist.txt' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/figuredata.xml"/>
        <param name='flash.dynamic.avatar.download.configuration' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/figuremap.xml"/>
        <param name='productdata.load.url' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/productdata.txt"/>
        <param name='furnidata.load.url' value="http://localhost/swf/gamedata/furnidata.xml"/>
        <param name='use.sso.ticket' value="1"/>
        <param name='sso.ticket' value=""/>
        <param name='processlog.enabled' value="0"/>
        <param name='client.starting' value="AAAAAAAAAA"/>
        <param name='flash.client.orogin' value="popup"/>
        <param name='nux.lobbies.enabled' value="true"/>
        <param name='county_code' value="NL"/>
        <param name='base' value="http://localhost/swf/"/>
        <param name='allowScriptAccess' value="always"/>
        <param name='menu' value="false"/>
        <param name='wmode' value="opaque"/>
    </object>

http://prntscr.com/nkm1qm
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question so that it presents a [mcve]. Images of text, like error messages, should not be presented with images, as images of text are not accessible, or searchable.

Comment: Code formatting